# Delete questions and answers using the android app

Tags: discussion, support, android-app

I recently gave a bad answer using the android app and I immediately noticed that it is bad since it doesn't answer the question. I wanted to delete it but I can't see that option in the android app. And I had no access to my laptop, therefore I received downvotes.

How to delete questions and answers from the android app?

Comment: Crappy workaround: Click on the timestamp of the question (NOT the answer), and then the "Open in Browser" link. From there you can delete your answer.

Comment: @user000001 ok thanks, I'll try that next time

Comment: @Mat we should ask questions regarding SE there from now on?

Comment: You can always ask on your "local" meta site, even for network-wide issues. But it's always good to search on the network-wide meta for things that apply globally.

Comment: @Mat normally your statement is correct, but the SE Team has asked that questions about the [ios-app] and [android-app] be asked on MSE.